# React Router Duplicate routes on Back Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a react app. It is working fine. It uses redux,react-router 3. The routes work fine, but when I press the back button, they route gets duplicated. For example from `localhost:3000/admin/main` which I am currently, when I go back, it goes to `localhost:3000/admin/admin/main`, which return not found.

Here is my  routes code:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="home" component={requireNoAuthentication(HomeContainer)} />
        <Route path="login" component={requireNoAuthentication(LoginView)} />
        <Route exact path="admin/user" component={requireAuthentication(UserView)} />
        <Route exact path="admin/main" component={requireAuthentication(UsersListView)} />
        <Route path="secure" component={requireAuthentication(CustomerView)} />
        <Route exact path="*" component={DetermineAuth(NotFound)} />
    </Route>
);
```

I also get a console error: `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`. If anyone can help it would be great thanks!!

Comment: try adding `/` before all your paths. `/admin/user` for example

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't solve the issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HOC` wrappers (`requireNoAuthentication` and `requireAuthentication`) and using `exact` (I think this might a react-router v4 only feature?) might be messing with your route history. Try restructuring your routes so that all of them fall under `App` -- some of the routes fall under `RequireAuth`, while the rest are public.

As a side note: you can avoid using `React.cloneElement` with passed down class `methods` and `state` by using `Redux` instead.

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { browserHistory, IndexRoute, Router, Route } from "react-router";
import App from "../components/App";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Info from "../components/Info";
import ShowPlayerRoster from "../components/ShowPlayerRoster";
import ShowPlayerStats from "../components/ShowPlayerStats";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";
import Sponsors from "../components/Sponsors";
import RequireAuth from "../components/RequireAuth";

export default () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route component={RequireAuth}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="roster" component={ShowPlayerRoster} />
        <Route path="roster/:id" component={ShowPlayerStats} />
        <Route path="schedule" component={Schedule} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="info" component={Info} />
      <Route path="sponsors" component={Sponsors} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "../routes";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**components/App.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
import Header from "./Header";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
  };

  isAuthed = () => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });

  unAuth = () =>
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false }, () => browserHistory.push("/"));

  render = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <Header
        isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
        unAuth={this.unAuth}
      />
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
        isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
        isAuthed: this.isAuthed
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

**components/RequireAuth.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Login from "./Login";

export default ({ children, isAuthenticated, isAuthed }) =>
  !isAuthenticated ? (
    <Login isAuthed={isAuthed} />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot. One question though. I am using redux, and I haven't used `REact.cloneElement` anywhere. Can you explain that?? ARE YOU REFERRING TO THE EXAMPLE??

Comment: I'll create another codebox for Redux later today. But yes, the example I've provided uses `React.cloneElement` in `App.js`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Really appreciated.

Comment: 404 for link to sandbox

Comment: This post is almost 2 1/2 years old and may no longer work with current packages. As such, I've removed the codesandbox link, but will keep the code as is.